# SetText on TextView crashes on NullPointerException

Tags: android

please I have this code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vystup);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    String pom = "AAA";
    data.setText(pom);
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vystup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="@string/vystup1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

But it crashes on line with

```
data.setText(pom)
```

on NullPointerException, because data is not connected to any widget, but why, I have connected it on line with:

```
data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vystup);
```

So, please, can you help me...what I have wrong?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here is my logcat:

```
04-01 21:09:00.198: W/dalvikvm(12575): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4112d9a8)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cz.pavel.testovacisettext/cz.pavel.testovacisettext.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at cz.pavel.testovacisettext.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-01 21:09:00.201: E/AndroidRuntime(12575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
```

I try to remove this part:

```
   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

But problem is still the same

**UPDATE 2**

Here is complete xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="cz.pavel.testovacisettext.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vystup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="@string/vystup1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: can you share the logcat ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com, try to post the stacktrace displayed on logCat to have more details about your problem, so we can help you faster :).

Comment: post the complete xml layout file

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vystup);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    String pom = "AAA";
    data.setText(pom);
}
```

Your textView is in the activity_main.xml but this part of your code :

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
```

will replace the current contentView which is activity_main to R.id.container if im not mistaking
try to remove that piece of code and try again...

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines

```
String pom = "AAA";
data.setText(pom);
```

before the Fragment Transaction

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vystup);
    String pom = "AAA";
    data.setText(pom);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

the transaction replace the current "contentView" from `activity_main` to `R.id.container` that doesn´t contain the `Textview` "data".